# Exception: No parsed pages. Please parse page first

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ms-word

I am trying to read a whole pdf file that is more then 250 pages. for that first i am converting my pdf to docx thorough the pdf2docx library.

here is a code;

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.save('file.docx')


url = file_path #(google drive url where file was uploaded)
response = requests.get(url)
my_raw_data = response.content

with open("my_pdf.pdf", 'wb') as my_data:
  my_data.write(my_raw_data)

open_pdf_file = open("my_pdf.pdf", 'rb')

cv = Converter(open_pdf_file)
cv.convert("roshni.docx")
Parse=parser.from_file("file.docx")
data=[]
for i in (Parse['content'].strip().split('\n')): 
  if len(i.split())<5:
    pass
  else: 
    data.append(i)
Text=data[1:-1]
```

But I am not able to read the file. getting error like "Exception: No parsed pages. Please parse page first.[image: here is the image of error.]"

How to solve this issue ? how to read a whole pdf using python ?

Comment: BTW: you could try to use `io.BytesIO()` to create file-like object in memory without writing file on disk. `Converter(io.Bytes(response.content))`

Comment: if you use `stream` in `requests.get(url, stream=True)` then `response` should be file-like object and it could work `Converter(response)`

Comment: If it can't find text then it may have nothing to convert. Did you check what you really have in file? Maybe file has only images or empty pages. Without file we can't test it .

Comment: I am using current version of the pdf2docx, and PyMuPDF

Comment: I have tried using requests.get(url, stream=True). but still it is not working. getting error like "TypeError: bad filename".
here is the code.
`import io
url = file_path
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
my_raw_data = response.content
cv=Converter(my_raw_data)`

also tried
`import io
url = file_path
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
cv=Converter(response)`

Comment: Tried using `import io
url = file_path
response = requests.get(url)
cv=Converter(io.BytesIO(response.content))`
getting error like "TypeError: bad filename"

Comment: here is link of pdf. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzwv0mjavy0n336/The-power-of-subconscious-mind-585.pdf?dl=0)